# In testcafe if we set disableScreenshots parameter to true than it ignores the t.screenshot() action and the takeOnFails parameter

Tags: testcafe

if we set disableScreenshots parameter to true than it  ignores the t.screenshot() action and the takeOnFails parameter. Is there a way we can only ignore  t.screenshot() action but it should still get the screenshot of failer which generated by the takeOnFails parameter. currenltly if I am setting disableScreenshots parameter to true than it ignores the t.screenshot() action and the takeOnFails parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent screenshots being taken only in the `takeScreenshot` action.
According to the documentation, the `--disable-screenshots` option prevents TestCafe from taking screenshots whenever a test fails or a screenshot action is executed:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402840/guides/intermediate-guides/screenshots-and-videos#disable-screenshots